# Trying to produce a table where the cost of an individual book is more than the average cost of all books

Tags: sql

Trying to produce a table where the cost of an individual book is more than the average cost of all books

```
SELECT book_num, book_title, book_cost
FROM (SELECT book_num, book_title, book_cost, Avg(book_cost) AS AVGPRICE
      FROM book
      GROUP BY book_num, book_title, book_cost)
WHERE book_cost > AVGPRICE
ORDER BY book_title;
```

Comment: You've not asked a question, not explained what the problem is that you're having with your existing SQL, and failed to supply any sample data or desired output. What exactly would you like us to help you with?

Comment: What's the problem? What's it giving and what do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT book_num, book_title, book_cost
FROM book
WHERE book_cost > (SELECT  Avg(book_cost) FROM book)
ORDER BY book_title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I used the ubiquitous pubs database)

```
DECLARE @avgprice money;

SET @avgprice = (SELECT  Avg(price) FROM titles);   

SELECT title, price, @avgprice as AveragePrice 
FROM titles 
WHERE price > @avgprice ORDER BY title;
```